# Browser events gets fired when applying style transform: scale(xValue, yValue)

Tags: javascript, browser, scale, css-transforms, dom-events

In my webpage, I need to handled changes using JavaSCript when transform property is applied to a div tag. My approach is using eventListeners. But I am not able to find out what event gets triggered when a div tag is scaled.

```
// html ement
<div id='my-container'> ... some conetent </div>

// applying CSS style by other modules using javaScript
 document.getElementById('my-container').style.transform ='scale(0.8,0.8)'

// My JS code to handled the support 'my-container' against scale css
document.getElementById('my-container').addEventListener('??????',console.log);
```

Please let me know is there any event gets triggered after scaling the element.

Or do I need to use any other way to handle this scenario?

**Note: tried animationstart, animationend, transitionend events listeners**

Comment: You don't need a event listener for this as the next line after scaling will get executed straight away.

Comment: I guess your question is the scaling animation which coming from CSS transition which JS won't be able to know when it's finished. (Probably could but hacky way). So rather using a timeout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect when CSS animations start and end with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796936/how-do-you-detect-when-css-animations-start-and-end-with-javascript)

Comment: I have tried with animation events, transform style does not trigger any animation events @RandyCasburn

Comment: Probably this answer is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425087/1926369

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to trigger a function when your `style` attribute changes. The `prop` argument in the `set` callback function defines the style changed, and so you can use an `if` statement to check what property you are changing.

```js
const elementStyle = new Proxy(document.getElementById('my-container').style, {set: function(o, prop, style) {
  if(prop == "transform") {
    // todo when style transform changes
    console.log("transform changed");
  }
  o[prop] = style;
}});

elementStyle.transform = "scale(0.8,0.8)"; // triggers console.log
elementStyle.color = "green"; // doesn't trigger function call
```

```html
<div id='my-container'> ... some conetent </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thanks for the answer, but it is only working if we are changing styles using elementStyle object. try once document.getElementById('my-container').style.transform ='scale(0.8,0.9)' separately. My point is what if it is changed from a different script, then how can i handle it.